# is there a way to generate a rig without controllers using rigify or delete the rigify controllers?

Tags: rigging, rigify

I need to rig a character to use with live mocap (rokoko) and the only thing i need is the weighted skeleton, i already tryed using rigify to create the rig and delete the controlers but it didnt went as expected, i dont know if there is a way to safely delete the controllers without blowing up the whole rig or if there is an option to generate the rig without controllers.(the controlers are the only thing interfering with the live mocap).

Comment: What do you mean by "generate the rig"? - That is done by using Rigify in Blender but if you just want the armature parented to your model so that you can use the armature bones to pose your model in Pose mode, you simply select the character, Shift-select the armature and use Ctrl-P > With Automatic Weights. There's also a [Blender addon for Rokoko](https://www.rokoko.com/integrations/blender) of course and lots of YT videos about it.